# ActionScript - Instantiate New Object From Instance?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, instance, arguments

how can i instantiate another class object from a class instance?

in the code below (which doesn't work) i'd like the function to return a new class instance based the passed argument's class.  in other words, i want the function to return a new instance of *MySprite* without having to call `new MySprite();`.

```
var mySprite:Sprite = new MySprite();
var anotherSprite:Sprite = makeAnotherSprite(mySprite);

function makeAnotherSprite(instance:Sprite):Sprite
    {
    return new getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(instance));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way than what you're trying to do, but should work.

```
function makeAnotherSprite(instance:Sprite):Sprite
{
var myClass:Class = Object(instance).constructor; 
return new myClass();
}
```

Comment: nice!  i forgot all about using the constructor property.  this is much cleaner than having to use the flash.utils static functions.  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your solution did almost work. Here's the corrected function:

```
function makeAnotherSprite(instance:Sprite):Sprite
{
    var qualifiedClassName:String = getQualifiedClassName(instance);
    var clazz:Class = getDefinitionByName(qualifiedClassName) as Class; 
    return new clazz();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make that:

```
return new (getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(instance)))();
```

(Brackets)